# How to fill in VALUE with JS element

Tags: javascript, html, hostname

I hope this is kinda clear to you all. 
I have a form where I add some hidden parameters, I also want to add the hostname in such a field.

```
<input type="hidden" id="URL" value="www.xxxx.xx" name="URL" />
```

However, I can get the hostname, for example via this JS:

```
document.getElementById("URL").innerHTML = 
window.location.hostname;
```

But in this way I only get it via the ID, which won't work to get it as a value. 
Do you have any idea how to get that filled in?
Thanks, Eelco

Comment: fill as `document.getElementById("URL").value = window.location.hostname;`

Comment: change to `document.getElementById("URL").value = window.location.hostname;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to the value of the element

```
document.getElementById("URL").value = window.location.hostname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it like this:

```
document.getElementById("URL").setAttribute(name, window.location.hostname);
```

You can create a new attribute for an element or set the value of the attribute like described here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

I hope it helps.

Comment: and what is the name?

Comment: @Martin54 name is the name of the created or altered attribute (if it already existed). You can set the name to that what you want (except keywords). For this case you can use host or hostname as the attribute name.